# Uniquely identify element for parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I want to populate an alert box with the inner.html of some element. But that element does not have an ID and I am not able to give it one, because I am coding a plugin not a page.

I know that the element is the only child element that is both:

- Of the class "icon25 icon_next_arrow"
- Of of several children of an element with id="co_documentFooterResultsNavigation"
- The only element that meets both the previous two criteria

How would I go about doing the equivalent of:

```
var x = document.getElementById("correctElement").innerHTML;
alert(x);
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML structure?

Comment: Is there no solution that will work for all structures which meet the above criteria?

Comment: It is hard to picture the HTML structure from your question. A short example would help a lot.

Comment: There might be. I'd just have an easier time visualizing a solution if I could see the HTML instead of just reading a description.

Comment: get children of element with id `co_documentFooterResultsNavigation` and match the class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is right?

```
var x = document.querySelector(
  '#co_documentFooterResultsNavigation icon25.icon_next_arrow'
);
alert( x );
```

Use querySelector instead getElementById.

Use click handler for first element:

```
var x = document.querySelector(
  '#co_documentFooterResultsNavigation icon25.icon_next_arrow'
);
x.onclick = function() {
  alert( x.innerText );
}
```

Emulate click with jQuery so easy:

```
$( x ).trigger( 'click' );
```

Comment: This seems to be correct.  Can you help me with one more small thing?  How would you go about clicking the element?  I know .click() works in the context of: document.getElementById('element').click();

Comment: Sample of above select only first element.
If need click handler: document.querySelector( '...' ).onClick = function() { ... }

Paste your code to ...

Comment: First Thanks!  Second, I'm not trying to handle a click, I'm trying to emulate one.

Comment: document.querySelector(
  '#co_documentFooterResultsNavigation icon25.icon_next_arrow'
).click()

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery .children() : https://api.jquery.com/children/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = $( ".icon25.icon_next_arrow" ).children();
    $( x ).css( "color", "blue" );
});
```

Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/m5gLrqq4/